# Delay by 1 millisecond not working?

Tags: java

I am trying to generate a number using:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()
```

I have to generate these numbers sometimes 5 times in a row, which happens so fast that they are the same (but I don't want them to be the same as we are using them as part of a unique field)

I thought I could put a delay in between when each one is generated, which would prevent them from being the same, using:

```
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1);
```

But this still generates the same number. It only seems to generate a new one if I increase it to about 60 and above. I am trying to understand why this is? Thanks

Comment: You can use `Thread.sleep(1)`. This will make your current thread to sleep for `1 milli-second`, giving you the delay that you want !

Comment: I have already tried Thread.sleep(1) and this didn't work. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you use `UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();`

Comment: Or possibly just `Math.random()' ... but it depends on why the OP is generating these numbers.

Comment: @markspace True. My assumption is OP wants some kind of UUID. But it's just an assumption.

Comment: @Elliot Yes, and I assumed she was trying seed or create a random number generator, but for all we know she really just wants `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()`, or something completely different.  It's really hard to guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to generate 5 numbers starting at the current time that aren't the same - which as far as *I* can tell is your only requirement - you can use

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();

long ts[] = { t, t+1, t+2, t+3, t+4 };
```

Thread.sleep is absurd here. The user (or whoever) should not experience a delay for something that can be computed now.

Answer (score 4):

The Java docs for Thread.sleep() says:

```
 Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the
 specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system
 timers and schedulers.
```

That bit about the "precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers" is pretty important.  I'd say that's why your not getting anything until you use `Thread.sleep(60)`: those system timers just aren't very accurate.

Now a better question is **why** are you trying to "generate numbers..."

Comment: Hmm, Wikipediea says "accuracy of a measurement system is the degree of closeness of measurements of a quantity to that quantity's actual (true) value."  I'd say that no difference between 59 and 1 isn't very accurate (close to the true value of 1 millisecond).

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for System.currentTimeMillis() says:

```
 "Note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond,
  the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system
  and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in
  units of tens of milliseconds."
```

From this, is it likely that your problem is not java - related, but rather your operating system is not keeping the time per - millisecond.

Answer (score -2):

Thread.sleep guarantees the Thread will sleep, but not for how long. It will definitely sleep, at least for 1 millisecond but your os may not give priority to jvm, or jvm may not give priority to the thread after 1 millisecond.

Comment: Why the hell are you downvoting this answer?

Comment: Because it's as if the OP said "my code doesn't compile," and you said "no it does." Please explain why your answer does not apply to the OP's operating system.

Comment: @djechlin Are you kidding? Where does he say his code does not compile?  And how is my answer different than the answer got 4 upvotes?

Comment: 1. I said "it's as if." I understand that you did not literally tell the OP that their code doesn't compile. I used metaphor. 2. Please read their complete answer. The bit where the answer says, "that bit where... is pretty important", is pretty important. All that happened in the answer was the OP said they had a problem and you said their code was supposed to work. This is useless, hence I downvoted.